# Multiple TempData variables passed to same action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I'm creating ASP.NET web application using MVC and Entity Framework. I have two different success messages I am passing to an index action for when a user clocks in or clocks out. The success message will print correctly when a user clocks in, but will not when a user clocks out for some reason.

The actions are very similar and I used all of the same conventions so I can't figure out why one would print and another would not. I've tried debugging and there are no red flags and everything updates in the database like it should. Is it not possible to pass multiple TempData variables to the same action?

Here is the relevant code:

Controller

```
        // GET: TimeClocks
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ClockInSuccess = TempData["ClockInSuccess"];
        ViewBag.ClockOutSuccess = TempData["ClockOutSuccess"];
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClockIn(TimeClock timeClock)
    {
        if(db.TimeClocks.ToList().Count == 1)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ExistsError", "You already clocked in at" + timeClock.ClockIn);
        }
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
        timeClock.ApplicationUser = currentUser;
        timeClock.ClockIn = DateTime.Now;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TimeClocks.RemoveRange(db.TimeClocks.ToList());
            db.TimeClocks.Add(timeClock);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["ClockInSuccess"] = "You clocked in successfully at " + timeClock.ClockIn;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", timeClock);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClockOut(TimeClock timeClock)
    {
        timeClock = db.TimeClocks.FirstOrDefault();
        if(timeClock.ClockIn == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("NullError", "You must clock in before you can clock out.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        timeClock.ClockOut = DateTime.Now;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(timeClock).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["ClockOutSuccess"] = "You clocked out successfully at " + timeClock.ClockOut;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", timeClock);
    }``
```

View

```
@model FinalProject.Models.TimeClock

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Employee Time Clock</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ClockIn", "TimeClocks")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Clock In" class="btn btn-lg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClockOut", "TimeClocks"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Clock Out" class="btn btn-lg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@{
    if (@ViewBag.ClockInSuccess != "")
    {
        <p class="alert-success">@ViewBag.ClockInSuccess</p>
    }
    else if (@ViewBag.ClockOutSuccess != "")
    {
        <p class="alert-success">@ViewBag.ClockOutSuccess</p>
    }
}


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense. Your view has `@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")` suggesting the view you have shown is not the `Index` view. And in your post methods, if the model is not valid then you are calling `return RedirectToAction("Index", timeClock);` but the `Index()` method does not accept a parameter so there is no point in the second parameter (not that it would work anyway). Very unclear what your trying to do and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

TempData is lost once you read it so you need to do a Peek or a Keep:

```
ViewBag.ClockInSuccess = TempData.Peek("ClockInSuccess");
ViewBag.ClockOutSuccess = TempData.Peek("ClockOutSuccess");
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818493/MVC-Tempdata-Peek-and-Keep-confusion